# Why Webview prevent showing a webpage when click a swf?

Tags: cocoa, safari, webview

Now I show a swf from web in my webview , but when I click the url address in the swf to show another page with my default web browser, I found the webveiw prevent to do it , Why ? How to allow it ?Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the `WebUIDelegate` protocol, specifically this delegate method:

```
- (WebView *)webView:(WebView *)sender createWebViewWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request;
```

If you've got an object registered as the `WebView`'s UI delegate then this method is called when the Flash plug-in sends a URL change request. You can then do what you want with the request. By default, the `WebView` just ignores it.